# Obtain node property values in an array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can I return a node property values in an array? Say I create the following node in neo4j:

```
CREATE (p:Person {name:'Ernesto', gender:'male', town:'Cham'})
```

I can produce the keys by using:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Ernesto'} )
RETURN keys(p)
```

will produce:

```
[name, gender, town]
```

what is the right method for obtaining:

```
['Ernesto', 'male', 'Cham']
```

as a collection, better yet, obtaining a map:

```
{name: 'Ernesto', gender: 'male', town: 'Cham'}
```

Not interested in obtaining this info visually as a node properties as it always contains the node id. I'm interested in a generic approach so it can be used variably.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to return all properties of a node with Cypher. Would be a great feature though.

You get something close to it with:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN str(n) LIMIT 1
```

This returns a string representation that you can parse in your application:

```
Node[817903]{key:"value", key2:"value2"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The **str** function might make it possible to scan through it, maybe using one of the available iterators and being able to produce the map inline?

Comment: I think you can't do that within your Cypher query. Try parsing it application side. It's not valid JSON unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the property values as an array:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Ernesto'})
RETURN [prop IN properties(p) | prop] AS propertyValues
```

This query uses a list comprehension to iterate over the properties of the node p and creates an array containing all the property values. The result will be ['Ernesto', 'male', 'Cham'].

To obtain the property values as a map:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Ernesto'})
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs([prop IN properties(p) | [prop, p[prop]]]) AS propertyMap
```

In this query, use the APOC library's map.fromPairs function to transform the properties into key-value pairs and then convert it into a map. The result will be {name: 'Ernesto', gender: 'male', town: 'Cham'}.